# iOS - Mudar a altura de um Text Field dentro do UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift

Eu tenho um layout que montei usando `StackView`. Entao eu tenho uma `StackView` vertical com alguns `TextField`, e duas `StackView`  horizontais dentro. Eu quero agora mudar a altura dos textfields, coisa que o inspector nao me deixa fazer.

O layout esta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E assim que está montado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe se é possivel fazer essa modificaçao na altura? Ou é algum problema de `constraint`?

Answer (score 0):

Para mudar a altura do textFiled você tem que colocar uma constraint na mesmo. Experimenta segurar `control` sobre o elemento de textField e em seguida arrastar em cima dele mesmo, a partir disso você vai selecionar `height`, a partir daí você vai selecionar o elemento textField que você colocou a constraint, e olhar o valor da constraint do lado direito do xcode, olhando as medidas. Procure pela constraint de altura que foi colocada e então mude o valor da mesma.

[image: Adicionando a altura do textField]

---

Lembrando que tem que mudar o valor da constraint e em seguida mandar atualizar a View que esta presente na tela, isso pode variar, algumas vezes precisa atualizar, outras vezes já é feito automaticamente.

[image: Mudando o valor da constraint]